# What happens to previous RDD when the next RDD is materialized?

Tags: apache-spark

In spark,I would like to know what happens to previous RDD when the next RDD is materialized.

let say I have the below scala code

```
val lines = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/data.txt")
val lineLengths = lines.map(s => s.length)
val totalLength = lineLengths.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
```

I have linesRDD is a base RDD 
 and similarly i have linesLengths RDD

I know that these two RDD gets materialized when reduce Action is invoked.

My question is while the data is flowing through these 2 RDD's , What happens to linesRDD when the linesLengthsRDD gets materialized .

once the linesLengthsRDD gets materialized then does the data inside linesRDD gets removed?

Let's say in production spark job there might 100 RDD's, a single Action is called against 100th RDD.

what happens to data in  1st RDD when the 99th RDD gets materialized?

Data in all RDD's get deleted only the respective final Action returned the respective output ?

Or

Data in each RDD gets removed automatically once that RDD passes its data to its next RDD as per DAG?

Answer (score 0):

Actually both lines and lineLength will hold their rdds after the reduce. You can think of the rdd as DAG of transformations, as you mentioned. So if later you would like to perform some other transformations on lines or lineLength you can. Even though they materialize during the reduce, unless you cache the directly, they will run through their transformations again when another action will be invoked on a DAG they belong to.

Comment: I am not applying  any cache operation on any RDD.  Then also both lines and lineLength will hold their  rdds DATA  after the reduce? my question is all about DATA in RDD's

Comment: They will remain the same as they were before the reduce. They don't actually hold the data. The data is retrieved only when an action is submitted and assigned to some variable.

Comment: Yes.When you call a Action then spark reads the data from source location and goes through all transformations. That means each RDD for each transformation gets materialized. My question is Does each RDD keeps the data till the action returned some output OR each RDD deletes that data  it keeps as soon as it send it sends its DATA to next RDD?

Comment: The data is transformed and if not cached not saved. So, I guess you can say it is "deleted".